# How do I make Win32 API calls from PHP?

Tags: php, winapi

I know that I can consume COM components but is there a way to directly call into the Win32 API's (user32.dll, advapi32.dll etc) from PHP or do I need to wrap in a PHP extension or COM object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The win32api support for php is very flaky. Have a look at this

http://php.net/manual/en/book.w32api.php

Comment: I think win32api got yanked. Phalanger would be nice but sadly not an option.

Comment: Hmm...I feel a COM wrapper is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

See the first comment [here](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.w32api.php):

> The only way I've been able to call Win32 API functions with PHP5 has been through COM and DynamicWrapper.
>
> Here's an example to play a beep sound with your computer speaker:

```
<?php
$com = new COM("DynamicWrapper");
$com->Register("KERNEL32.DLL", "Beep", "i=ll", "f=s", "r=l");
$com->Beep(5000, 100);
?>
```

You can get an updated DynamicWrapper [here](http://glsft.free.fr/index.php?option=content&task=view&id=47). You have to register it with regsvr32.