# How to make PHP output a sound (beep)?

Tags: php, python, beep, synthesizer

What's the PHP verson of this python code?

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(537, 2000)
```

Answer (score 9):

php is mostly used on webservers, so what the use beeping there, and you can't beep on user computer through php, as php is translated into HTML, which has no such method.

If you want to have Win32 calls have a look at: [How do I make Win32 API calls from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411657/how-do-i-make-win32-api-calls-from-php)
also the [Win32 Beep Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679277%28VS.85%29.aspx)

But if you want to have beep sound on user browser better [embed audio into the HTML](http://www.world-voices.com/resources/addaud.html) itself.

Edit: [Another method for just the beep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php):

```
<?php
  function beep ($int_beeps = 1) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $int_beeps; $i++): $string_beeps .= "\x07"; endfor;
    isset ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']) ? false : print $string_beeps;
  }
?>
```

This will not do anything when running through a browser, if running through a shell it will produce an audible beep $int_beeps times.  This should work on Windows, Unix, etc.

Comment: Believe it or not, but it's even possible to make desktop apps with PHP and GTK+...

Comment: yes there winbinder application allowing to create desktop apps with php :)

Comment: I know, but i used the word 'mostly', I never seen anyone writing a desktop apps with PHP

Comment: I know a guy who probably would, if I didn't constantly hack away at him for suffering from PHP fanboyness... :P

Comment: maybe he needs a beep on his server for every web access... like a Geiger counter. Think about it, it's not that bad as idea :)

Comment: This is not equivalent PHP version.

Comment: @unknown That's because there is no easy, equivalent PHP version.

Comment: I showed you the way, what you mean by the equivalent PHP. I don't think there is any other way other then embedding audio (either through flash like justin said) or using Win32 API for server.

Comment: @Stefano: That would be incredibly annoying for anyone working near that server :P

Answer (score 3):

This one works with the standard/built-in beep sound. (more of a 'doink' sound)

Also works on any platform.

Super simple, copy-paste code.

```
function beep()
{
    fprintf ( STDOUT, "%s", "\x07" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried what Tor Valamo suggested, but I still couldn't get the sound to play.

I would simply get a representation of the chr(7) on my screen but no sound when I used:

```
system('cmd /k go.bat')
```

And I would get nothing at all if I used:

```
exec('cmd /k go.bat')
```

Instead i used either of:

```
exec('start /MIN go.bat')
exec('cmd.exe /k start /MIN go.bat')
```

the only side effect is that a cmd.exe does flash, so the /MIN ensures that it only flashes to the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Never mind, I thought you just wanted a 'beep', not a TONE.

Old post, not answering the question:

You'd need to make a .bat file, so:
Open cmd

```
copy con go.bat [Enter]
@echo off [Enter]
echo [Ctrl+G] [Enter]
[Ctrl+Z] [Enter]
```

This looks like:

```
C:\DEV\test>copy con go.bat
@echo off
echo ^G
^Z
    1 file(s) copied.
```

Now you just call go.bat from PHP through exec() or system() or something. You need to make go.bat through cmd though, in order for the Ctrl+G character to be correct.

Comment: But still you can't see the freq and duration, you need to use Win32 Beep API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Of course people write GUI apps in PHP - that's what wxPHP is for.

Install mpg321 - a tiny sound app:

```
exec("mpg321 --quiet --gain 10 /path/to/beep.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

**EZ way:**

**you can get help from html :**

```
echo "<audio src='http://freesoundeffect.net/sites/default/files/incorrect-answer--6-sound-effect-99679566.mp3' autoplay ></audio>";
```

> this code play beep sound in background and you can change .mp3 file

Answer (score 0):

this generates a beep, but unlike winsound, does not allow you to specify `frequency, duration`..

```php
function cli_beep()
{
    if (is_callable('ncurses_beep')) {
        ncurses_beep();
        ncurses_flash();
    } else {
        fprintf(STDOUT, "%s", "\x07");
    }
}
```