# Is there any way to get a beep sound in PHP web development?

Tags: php, service, web

Adding beep sound on successful form submission doesn't have anything to do with **PHP development**. PHP is just a server side language.

But I want to add beep sound when an error message/or other mentioned mandatory message occurred on my website submission form.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: use JavaScript to play a beep

Comment: You mean you want the server to beep whenever a user submits a form with invalid data?

Comment: Exactly!! I am asking the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make Javascript beep?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link below which is already answered clearly for your question, (Using PHP)

[How to make PHP output a sound (beep)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919826/how-to-make-php-output-a-sound-beep)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by embedding it in the html.
Check this one out

[How do I make Javascript beep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep)