# Send php command to an open command window

Tags: php, windows, command, command-prompt

I want to send a command (EX: ipconfig/all) to an already open command prompt or console.

```
$out=shell_exec('ipconfig/all');
echo '<pre>'.$out.'</pre>';
```

This works but runs on its own, I would like to send commands to a cmd that already open
[[image: Open CMD]]

I have gotten close..

Using [sendkeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat)

Java script it pops up the right window but does not enter the text..

***using***: sendKeys.bat "Asheron's Call | ACEmulator - v1.57.4468.20231231202603-master-4d73c70 -- Server Binary Update Available" acecommands{ENTER}

Pops up the right window but does not enter the text. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have gotten close...

Comment: What on earth is the use case for this?

Comment: I am working on creating a private game server Headend. I need a way to send command to the server Command windows. So far I can send a command using VBS but I cant figure out how to send it with input like command.vbs /DoSomething

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call winapi functions from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155827/how-to-call-winapi-functions-from-php)

Comment: I think it does...But its way over my head, guess I will just have to jump in and learn.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by a "headend"? Not a technical term I'm familiar with. But are you saying that there is a programming already running in the command window,  and you want to send a message to it? Or you want to enter text into that window from PHP, as if the user was typing it into the command window? I wasn't entirely sure from the description. And is the command which is running a program you wrote, or a 3rd-party product?

Comment: Headend= Website you login to to control a privet game server.