# "Choose folder" from PHP CLI

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I use PHP CLI a lot for writing scripts that help me out in tasks that can be automated. Currently I can only use the working directory (or a relative path thereof) to load and save to/from.

For the task I'm trying to do now, I want to choose a destination folder that may not be the same as the source.

Rather than having to type in the path (or copy/paste it), I was wondering if there's any way to invoke the "Choose folder" dialog instead.

Can this be done? I'm open to "hack" options too, such as a small program that just invokes the dialog and returns the chosen path or something.

Comment: It's possible, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411657/how-do-i-make-win32-api-calls-from-php

Comment: @user4035 Unfortunately it seems all the links in there are long dead.

Comment: What about the 2-nd answer? Can you call Win32 API from php?